# Why it says the file is empty?

Tags: java, file

I have a method that writes integer array into a file.
When I read it with a method that brings those ints as array it's working.
But when **I try** to count how many ints it says it's empty.

The same code is written on other computer systems. and it's working for him, the SAME code!

I already put the "buffer" byte array into the read method. still not working

```java
File file = new File("/home/arad/Desktop/intFile.bin");
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
//exampleWriteIntegerArray(arr, file);
reverseThisFile(file);

static void reverseThisFile(File file){

    File newFile = new File("/home/arad/Desktop/newIntegerFile.bin");
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println(file.length());
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer  = new byte[4];
        int actuallyRead;
        while((actuallyRead = inputStream.read()) != -1){
            counter++;``
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Comment: Tried to start your IDE as admin?

Comment: Is your name "arad"?  Is your friend's name "arad"?  Might that make a difference?  (Hint: look at the code ...)

Comment: This looks fishy `inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);`

Comment: Why pass a reference to `File` into the. method if you're just going to ignore it?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer why would running your IDE as admin (a genuinely terrible idea) help?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer - it not only looks fishy, creating a file for writing (new FileOutputStream) actually deletes its content (should not have deleted your answer)

Comment: @StephenC we both have different computers, my path to the file need be /home/arad....

Comment: @DavidTonhofer but my friends code is the exact same code but it works for him.

Comment: "SAME code" is very relative - for sure posted code is NOT the one being executed (compile error) and are both computers running same operation system? both have the folders `/home/arad/Desktop`? (sure that calling `new FileOutputStream` on my system WILL delete the file contents (when closing ))

Comment: @BoristheSpider It worked for me few times. Why do you think it's a terrible idea?

Comment: just copy `System.out.println(file.length());` after the `new FileOutputStream(file);` statement to check its (new) length (or comment the later one, no need to open an output)

Comment: If the pathnames in the code are different, then it is NOT the exact same code.   Seriously dude ... if you are going to misuse the English language like that, people will never understand you.  And if we can't understand you, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer because if you don't understand enough about why your code isn't working that trying random things is all you can think of it's a great way way brick your computer. It's a bit like running commands with `sudo` when they don't work. An IDE should only ever be run as your user.

Comment: Post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BoristheSpider I was actually thinking more of problems with access rights of his IDE to local data, which could possibly be bypassed as an administrator.

Comment: only the path is different. im not running the IDE as adminstrator.he uses Windows i use Ubuntu.

Comment: at Windows (tested) `new FileOutpuStream` will cause the file to be truncated (length = 0) as I already wrote (3rd time now!!)... at Ubuntu probably too...  have you tried commenting that (unused) line?

Answer (score 3):

Is something wrong in lines (input and output files are same):

```
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file); //comment this line
```

Name your variables better (outputFile, inputFile)... Also output stream outputStream is not closed... Try first just to print on console, ...

Answer (score 3):

> he uses Windows i use Ubuntu

I suspect this is the root of the difference, in conjunction with this code:

```java
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

In the first line, you're opening the existing file to read it. In the second line, you're creating a new, empty file. Should `inputStream` read from that empty file, or from the file that existed before you created the new one? I *believe* that the behaviour of Windows and Linux (and their file systems) may differ there.

I would strongly suggest that you don't do that.

Two alternative options:

- Use two different files. Read from one, write to the other.
- Do all the reading first, *then* do all the writing.

In both of these options, you never have an input and output stream to the same file at the same time... it's that part that's the recipe for problems.